# Calling popover from a menu item crash

Tags: cocoa, swift, popover

I have a toolbar button

```
@IBOutlet weak var testButton: NSToolbarItem!
```

The button call a popover and works fine.

But if i try and call the popover from a top menu item i get a crash.
I have amended the location of the popover to appear below the testButton just as it normally would. (commented below)

```
@IBAction func menuPreviewAndTestAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    var returnedHtmlString = checkEverythingAndCreateTheEncodedHtml(testButton)
    setEncodedHtmlToPreview(returnedHtmlString)
    var thebounds = self.testButton.view?.bounds // so i am givving bounds of button that narmally calls poover
    testingPopover.showRelativeToRect(thebounds!, ofView: sender as NSView, preferredEdge: NSMaxYEdge) // crashes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh dear... I missed changing the ofView, all sorted with :

```
var thebounds = self.testButton.view?.bounds
        var theview = self.testButton.view
        testingPopover.showRelativeToRect(thebounds!, ofView: theview! as NSView,      preferredEdge: NSMaxYEdge)
```